# Exception not passing IOError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, python-2.7, ioerror, except

I have a simple game I'm working on in py 2.7 that uses pickle to read and write save files.

I'm self-taught, and I just started learning like a week ago. I usually can find solutions to my problems online, but this one is taking way too long for what it would accomplish, so I'm asking for a little help.

The *problem* is that I have this try/except

```
        f = file("VTSave2.pkl", "rb")
        try:
            game = load(f)
            print "Game has been loaded from save 2."
        except IOError:
            pass
```

in a save-reading thing. VTSave2.pkl does not currently exist- I'm using this fact to test the try/except.

While I do get the appropriate error, [Errno 2], the IOError passer doesn't do squat. Instead of "load cancelled" I get a quit program and a traceback.

Am I making any dumb mistakes? Anything I should know? Any more information I should give? Thanks a bunch for your time!

*Edit: Thank you! It works now. Since I've had someone try to "correct" the formatting of the code, and it ended up breaking my prog when I adopted it, I've taken out all code no longer relevant to the question to try to avoid baiting erroneous cleanup. Thank you!*

proper working code:

```
    try:
        f = open("VTSave2.pkl", "rb")
        game = load(f)
        print "Game has been loaded from save 2."
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is raising the exception

```
f = file("VTSave2.pkl", "rb")
```

you need to move it after the `try:`

If you read the traceback carefully, you should see that the exception is raised at that line number

Aside: `file()` is deprecated. You should use `f = open("VTSave2.pkl", "rb")`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you! That fixed it! Thanks a bunch, and you helped so quickly. Have a good day. :3

Answer (score 0):

Your `print "Load cancelled."` is in the `else` part which will not be executed as you are in `if`.

You may want to re-factor it.

Comment: Actually, that part works fine. It's to catch a confirmation other than "y", i.e. "Are you sure you want to overwrite the current game with save 2? (y/n): n
Load cancelled." That's from the running prog. I have also added a print to except to elaborate on "file not found", to differentiate from the user cancelling the function. Thanks for the advice, though! :D